# How to show value from controller in html element added with append() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

I'll appreciate any help. My problem: I can't show value from `$scope.info` in my view. I don't have direct access to html, so I can change DOM only via js. 
I created new element and added it to the DOM with `append()` method

```
$scope.info = {
  clicks: 15862,
  spent: '$124',
  created: '04/08/2017',
  author: 'John Kovalenko',
  name: 'Advertise US'
};

var info = document.createElement('div');
info = angular.element(info).attr({
  'ng-bind': 'info',
  'class': 'statistic-info'
});
angular.element(infoContainer).append(info[0]);
```

I created example here.
http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/13598/

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `$compile` when you manually inject anything that uses directives

```
  var info = angular.element('<div>').attr({
    'ng-bind': 'info.author',
    'class': 'statistic-info'
  });

  info = $compile(info)($scope);

  angular.element(infoContainer).append(info);
```

Be sure to inject `$compile` wherever you use it

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/13618/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is to add the data into the HTML content before appending it. Since you have an object, I've supplied one of it's properties in the snippet below.

What is happening is your page loads, and the digest cycle has already completed. What you are appending is simply plain text, and therefor is not interpolated. This method that I am providing will not provide two-way binding. If that is required, you should be using a directive.

```
var infoTwo = '<div><p>' + $scope.info.clicks + '</p></div>';
```

**That said, [charlieftl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966) has the best answer.**